# How to pass through "multi factor" authentication with mechanize?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, screen-scraping, mechanize

I am attempting to log into a site via Mechanize that is proving to be a bit of a challenge.  I can get past the first two form pages, but then after submitting an ID and password, I get a third page prior to being able to go into the main content that I'm attempting to scrape.

In my case I have the following Ruby source that gets me to the point where I'm hitting a roadblock:

```
agent = Mechanize.new


start_url = 'https://sub.domain.tld/action'

# Get first page
page = agent.get(start_url)

# Fill in the first ID field and submit form
login_form = page.forms.first
id_field = login_form.field_with(:name => "ctl00$PageContent$Login1$IdTextBox")
id_field.value = "XXXXXXXXXXX"

# Get the next password page & submit form:
page = agent.submit(login_form, login_form.buttons.first)
login_form = page.forms.first
password_field = login_form.field_with(:name => "ctl00$PageContent$Login1$PasswordTextBox")
password_field.value = "XXXXXXXXXXX"

# Get the next page and... 
page = agent.submit(login_form, login_form.buttons.first)

# Try to go into the main content, just to hit a wall. :s
page = agent.click(page.link_with(:text => /Skip to main/))
```

The contents of the third page as per the `mechanize` agent output is:

https://gist.github.com/5ed57292c8f6532352fd

As you may note from this, it seems that one should be able to simply use `agent.click` on the first link to get on into the main content.  Unfortunately, this is simply looping back to this page.  Each time this loads I see that it is loading a new page, but it ends up having the precise same contents each time.  Something is preventing me from being able to go on in through this multi-factor login to the main content it would seem, but I can't put my finger on what that might be.

Here is the `page.content` from that third request: http://f.cl.ly/items/252y261c303R0m2P1R0j/source.html

Any thoughts on what may be stopping me from going forward to content here?

Comment: I cannot add the real link as it is behind a secure banking system.

Comment: What I shared above is precisely what I get in terms of content.  I initially would expect simply a verification of whether or not I am triggering this properly or missing some detail.  Would it help if I were to massage the page resources (js, stylesheets, etc.) into the shared html?  Are there any other aspects of the resultant page that I'm missing in terms of sharing that would be helpful to be able to verify or correct the way I am calling the last `.click` method that *should* be activating access into the main page? I notice a few URL redirects after I click it in a regular browser.

Comment: Let's start over. The `Skip to main` link is a fragment. A link whose href looks like `#foo` for example doesn't go anywhere. Do you get it?

Comment: Two possible things could be happening. The first as noted is that the link is porbably loading some javascript, in that case mechanize won't help you probably use [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/). The second optinons is that the load requires some specific cookies of some kind to authenticate.

Comment: Something to consider: If you are using a banking system, and you are using their approved methods to access their system, and you are having problems, the perhaps the best way of dealing with this is to contact their IT or API support people. Trying to scrape pages on a banking site isn't really the best way to go about gathering data these days, especially from those sort of institutions, and is a good way to get banned and possibly your account closed. They're a bit sensitive about these sort of things.